# Firebase Login with twitter in android, how to add email

Tags: android, twitter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have implemented Firebase Auth with Gmail, Facebook, and Twitter and at very first I was not able to get email whenever I used Twitter the value returned always `null`, but after some digging I found solution and now I am getting email address of user by requesting it separately, but how can I add this email to Firebase now?

```
 protected void handleTwitterSession(TwitterSession session) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleTwitterSession:" + session);

    AuthCredential credential = TwitterAuthProvider.getCredential(
            session.getAuthToken().token,
            session.getAuthToken().secret);

    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(context, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    Log.e(TAG, "user:" + task.getResult().getUser().getUid() + "  :  " +  task.getResult().getUser().getDisplayName() + " : "
                          +  task.getResult().getUser().getEmail() + " :  "+  task.getResult().getUser().getPhotoUrl());

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Above is the method I am using right now and there is no way to add email and on my firebase dashboard it shows empty value for email

[image: empty value for mail]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can update current user's email address by calling `user.updateEmail()`

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

user.updateEmail("user@example.com")
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "User email address updated.");
            }
        }
    });
```

[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#set_a_users_email_address) is official document from firebase